# Usar múltiplos Schemas com Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Estou começando a trabalhar com o Entity Framework, e preciso de algum exemplo de como posso definir para minhas tabelas os Schema's que cada uma está contida. Minha base de dados foi criada como no exemplo:

```
/*schema [Pes] -> relativo ao contexto Pessoa*/
Pes.Pessoa; 
Pes.PessoaFisica; 
Pes.EstadoCivil;  

/*schema [Sis] -> relativo ao contexto do Sistema*/
Sis.Versao;
Sis.Configuracao;
Sis.Usuario;
```

Partindo dessa estrutura, como posso passar para o EntityFramework que a tabela `Versao` esta definida no Schema `[Sis]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o [DataAnnotation Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) pra isso

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("Pes.Pessoa")]
public class Pessoa
{ ... }
```

Ou, se você usa FluentApi, pode fazer desta forma

```
public class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>().ToTable("Pessoa", "Pes");            
    }
}
```

Você também pode definir o *schema* padrão, dessa forma

```
 modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("DefaultSchema");
```

Comment: gostei do DataAnnotation, eu trabalhando dessa forma fica declarado diretamente na class somente, não preciso especificar mais nada no DbContext?

Comment: Nope. Nada mais.